# SQL function to convert a string into a time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this string: `PT0H8M30S`. The number before the "H" represent the hours, the number before the "M" represent minutes and the number before the "S" represent the seconds....how to convert it only into minutes using an SQL function?
The result should be: 8,5 minutes

Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: What about `PT` at the beginning of the string? Will you neglect it always? Will it always be two chars?

Comment: This is going to be something of a beast to handle with a SQL Server query.  Is there any chance you could do this work in your application layer before you bring the data into SQL Server?

Comment: Also, will there always be a H, M and an S part? E.g. could the input also be PT8M?

Comment: You say the result for this is `'8,5 minutes'` too. That isn't a time either, that's another string. If you have a value like `'PT21H30M0S'` would you expect the value `'21.5 hours'`? A time, in SQL Server, is generally provided in the format `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Also, will there always be a H, M and an S part? E.g. could the input also be PT8M?  yes it is possible...it's depend

Comment: You say the result for this is '8,5 minutes' too. That isn't a time either, that's another string. If you have a value like 'PT21H30M0S' would you expect the value '21.5 hours'? A time, in SQL Server, is generally provided in the format hh:mm:ss? you are right 8,5 minutes is a string as well but I need only that the fuction will return  "8,5"... in this case..... PT21H30M0S' would you expect the value '21.5 hours' in this case only "21.5"

Comment: That's an ISO-8601 *duration* string, not a time.

Comment: @Rhaker a duration could be more than 1 day, eg `P2DT3H4M`. Are you sure you'll never encounter a duration greater than 1 day? On the client side you coudl use NodaTime's PeriodPattern class in C#, or Java's Duration class to parse the value

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I m sure that it's always PT but I can recive as input also something like that: PT8M or PT8M13S....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the base string functions in SQL Server (`PATINDEX`, `CHARINDEX`, and `SUBSTRING`) to parse your time string.  To get the *ending* point of each unit, we can look for `H`, `M`, or `S`.  To get the *starting* point, we can look for either the one or two digits which immediately precedes the particular time unit.  This leads to some verbose SQL Server code, but it is fairly robust to the presence/absence of any time unit, in any order of appearance.

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'PTx10H48M30S' AS string UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P2DT3H4M'
)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('D', string) > 0
         THEN
             CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]D%', string) > 0
                  THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]D%', string), 2)) * 24 * 60
                  ELSE CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]D%', string), 1)) * 24 * 60 END
         ELSE 0.0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('H', string) > 0
         THEN
             CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]H%', string) > 0
                  THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]H%', string), 2)) * 60
                  ELSE CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]H%', string), 1)) * 60 END
         ELSE 0.0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('M', string) > 0
         THEN
              CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]M%', string) > 0
                  THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]M%', string), 2))
                  ELSE CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]M%', string), 1)) END
         ELSE 0.0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('S', string) > 0
         THEN
             CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]S%', string) > 0
                  THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]S%', string), 2)) / 60
                  ELSE CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]S%', string), 1)) / 60 END
         ELSE 0.0 END
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you so much! that is exactly what I expected to obtain.

Comment: The string is an ISO8601 duration. `PT` represents durations less than 1 day. It could easily be `P2DT3H4M`. Example taken from Java's [Duration class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). Which btw probably means we can use it with SQL Server 2019 ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I answered based on the information in front of me at the time.  If SQL Server doesn't have a built in way to handle this, then the best thing to do might be to parse in the application layer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know, but I remember seeing this string in a previous SO question. Don't remember if it was about T-SQL or C#. If one could deploy NodaTime to SQL Server, the [PeriodPattern](https://nodatime.org/2.3.x/api/NodaTime.Text.PeriodPattern.html) could be used. I'm not sure if it will work with the latest SQLCLR restrictions though

Comment: +1 for giving set-based solution (instead of UDF). (PS: it will fail on 'different' notations of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations possibilities, but it will work nicely for the (original) request.)

Comment: @deroby I sort of half suspected an ace up the sleeve somewhere.  I was thinking the string was some arbitrary homework format.  But now I see it is an ISO time string, all of whose edge cases my answer does not cover.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your string work extremely well bu tin case I have only this input: PT8M or PT8M13S ? how can I manage them? thank you in advance

Comment: @Rhaker I updated my answer, which should be robust to _any_ ISO input now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Now is perfect!!! YOU are A SQL MASTER.. I really hope I will reach your level! Did you learn everything by yourself ?

Comment: @Rhaker I live on Stack Overflow, this is how I got good.  Actually, I'm really an AI program, sort of like Agent Smith in the Matrix movies.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ohhh that is the reason!! so...keep in touch @AgentSmith!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that first tries to convert it to a TIME via replacements.

Because once that you have a TIME datatype it's easy to get the minutes from it.

```
SELECT col, 
(CASE 
 WHEN col LIKE 'PT%H%M%S' 
 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(col,3,LEN(col)),'H',':'),'M',':'),'S','') AS TIME))/60.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
 WHEN col LIKE 'PT%M%S' 
 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col,'PT','0:'),'M',':'),'S','') AS TIME))/60.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
 WHEN col LIKE 'PT[0-9]M' OR col LIKE 'PT[0-9][0-9]M' 
 THEN CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(col,'PT',''),'M','') AS DECIMAL(10,2))
 END) AS col_minutes
FROM
(values 
 ('PT0H8M30S')
,('PT10H08M05S')
,('PT8M30S')
,('PT8M')
,('Blah')
) AS data(col);
```

Returns:

```
col         col_minutes
----------- ------
PT0H8M30S   8.50
PT10H08M05S 608.08
PT8M30S     8.50
PT8M        8.00
Blah        NULL
```

The CASE is just to make sure that the string is in the expected format.

Comment: also your answer is perfect! thank you! ...in case I have only PT8M as input?

Comment: @Rhaker Well, that's easy if it's only that extra format. Just add another `WHEN` to the `CASE`.  I've added it to the SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much... you are right it is easy but I tried before reciving your answer but I forgot to change from second to minute!! shame on me!

Comment: I PROMISE you is the last question... I tried to manage this case : PT8M08S with another WHEN -CASE but it's not working!!! thank you in advance

Comment: @Rhaker But I think you should go with Tim's solution after all. Since that should work for any of those PT formats.

Comment: thanks for the advice!!...I figure it out to add to your solution all the other case!!